# formatting the output of a .txt in powershell

Tags: powershell, text

After a week of attempts I have to ask you this.

File input:

```
DD/MM                                                                               

27,28   

14,21                                                                                                               
1                                                                                                              
15                                                              

7                                                                                                                   
12                                                                                                                  
2,15                                                                                                                
25
```

Each line of this file represents a month, so even if it´s empty, it should still count so the formatting can happen. Then based on file input, the desired output is:

Desired Output:

```
DD/MM
27/02
28/02
14/04
21/04
01/05
15/06
07/09
12/10
02/11
15/11
25/12
```

What I got so far and stuck here:

```
#getting the content into an array and formatting the .DAT file 
$lines = Get-Content $outfileBR

If ($lines[0] -eq "DD/MM") {
     $HEADER = $lines[0] + $linebreak
} 

If ($lines[1] -eq '') {
     continue
} Else {
     $BRFILE  = $lines[1].SUBSTRING(0,2) + "/01" + $linebreak
     $BRFILE += $lines[1].SUBSTRING(3,2) + "/01" + $linebreak        
}

If ($lines[2] -eq '') {
     continue
} Else {
     $BRFILE2  = $lines[2].SUBSTRING(0,2) + "/02" + $linebreak
     $BRFILE2 += $lines[2].SUBSTRING(3,2) + "/02" + $linebreak
}

If ($lines[3] -eq '') {
     continue
} Else {
     $BRFILE3  = $lines[3].SUBSTRING(0,2) + "/03" + $linebreak
     $BRFILE3 += $lines[3].SUBSTRING(3,2) + "/03" + $linebreak
}

Set-Content $BRdatFile ($HEADER + $BRFILE + $BRFILE2 + $BRFILE3)
```

Result:

```
DD/MM
  /01
  /01
27/02
28/02
  /03
  /03
```

Like I said, each line refers to a month, but if the line is empty (like shown in input file) I´ll not show it in the output. But on my result it´s appearing as /01 for January, /03 for march and so on.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: your input file contains 12 lines including the header, though in your screenshot the last month is shown as December (12). I think you forgot to include an empty line after the line containing "15" (for June).

Comment: Hi Ronald, thanks for your help here. The copy & paste did not work very well. You´re right, an empty line related to August is missing after 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achieving this in PowerShell is as easy as this:

```
"DD/MM";
$lines = Get-Content $ENV:TEMP\input.txt;
for($c = 1; $c -lt $lines.Count; $c++) 
{ 
    $line = $lines[$c]; 
    if(!$line) { continue; }

    $line.Split(',') | % { '{0:00}/{1:00}' -f [int] $_, $c } 
}

27/02
28/02
14/04
21/04
01/05
15/06
07/08
12/09
02/10
15/10
25/11
```

**Edit**: fixed `$day`/ `$_`

Comment: _A quick question before I try to answer your question_ If you are not sure  why did you answer? Asking the OP in a comment would be a better idea no?

Comment: @Matt I studied his output and came to the conclusion that the output does not match his description. Maybe I should have added my initial sentence as a comment. I still think my answer is correct. thanks for the hint

Comment: I agree that your output is _almost_ correct. It looks like the op wants slashes in the date. Forgive me as I was being nit picky with your wording.

Comment: @Matt easy - I corrected that as well - 4 eye principle

Comment: `$day` is undefined. `$day -> $_`

Comment: I was testing this but getting an error: Cannot convert value "          " to type "System.Int32". Error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
At D:\DesktopHol.PS1:67 char:28
+     $line.Split(',') | % { '{0:00}/{1:00}' -f [int] $_, $c }
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Comment: according to your error message, you are using a *SPACE* somewhere in your supposed to be *EMPTY* lines - this is the reason for getting this type conversion error. If you use empty lines as described in you OP then this error will not occur.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to the answer given by Ronald Rink 'd-fens', I would do a loop within a loop, but since we know how many lines there should be in the file, I would do this:

```
#Get content of input file
$FileIn = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt
#Start array for output with header record
[array]$FileOut += 'DD/MM'
#Loop 12 times, once for each month
ForEach($Month in (1..12)){
    #Split the relevant line, and for each entry add a line to the output file
    If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($FileIn[$Month])){Continue}
    $FileIn[$Month].Split(',') | ForEach{
        $FileOut += '{0}/{1}' -f $_, $Month
    }
}
#Output the new file
$FileOut | Set-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.txt
```

**Edit:** I fixed 2 issues. I had [1..2] which should have been (1..12), and used the `$_` reference instead of `$Month` (which should work anyway, but it's bad form imho).

Comment: Hi @TheMadTechnician I get an error on `ForEach($Month in [1..12])` saying `Missing type name after '['.` (running PoSH 5.1.14393.693 on Windows 10.

Comment: Here are a few suggested corrections: `[array]$FileOut = @('DD/MM')`,  `[1..12] -> @(1..12)` , `$FileIn[$_] -> $FileIn[$Month]` , and `-f $_ -> -f $_.trim()`

Comment: @BenH Good call! Since it's a loop it'll technically work with `$_`, but I should use `$Month`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' Yeah, that was my bad. It should have been `(1..12)` instead of `[1..12]`. I have updated the answer to reflect that.